# AngularJS ng-class not applying css styles

Tags: angularjs

I have a company site that I am developing with AngularJS and I am having some troubles with `ng-class`

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="timeEntry.php" ng-class="{{(userRole.admin) ? '' : 'inactive'}}">
    LINK
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.inactive {
    pointer-events : none;
    cursor         : default;
}
```

Chrome Inspect Element:

```
<a href="timeEntry.php" ng-class="inactive">
    LINK
</a>
```

Obviously I have tested `class="inactive"` and it is working as it should, Chrome's view source appears to be showing me something that should be working but it is not being applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming userRole.admin is a boolean, this should work

```
<a href="timeEntry.php" ng-class="{ inactive: !userRole.admin }">
    LINK
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
<a href="timeEntry.php" ng-class="{inactive:userRole.admin}">Link</a>
```

you can also have multiple conditions in the object, just put commas between them. The format is `cssClass:<boolean expression>`

Answer (score 1):

ng-class expects an expression, so in your original code the part inside {{}} is being evaluated, and then angular is again evaluating the result of that, trying to interpret 'inactive' as a variable name. If you want to use a ternary just omit the {{}} from your original code

```
<a href="timeEntry.php" ng-class="userRole.admin ? '' : 'inactive'">
LINK
```

But for this particular example, the solutions provided by others using the object format are preferred.